# android studio no suitable method for .add

Tags: java, android

Hey everybody I'm just trying to follow a course about developing android projects but here i got an obstacle (error) on my way. However i type every bit of code as it is in the course i got this error.

```
Error:(19, 21) error: no suitable method found for add(int,PlaceholderFragment)
method FragmentTransaction.add(Fragment,String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to Fragment)
method FragmentTransaction.add(int,Fragment) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; PlaceholderFragment cannot be converted to Fragment)
```

Here is my activity_main layout file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn.MainActivity"
   tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"/>
```

Here is my fragment_main.xml layout file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn.MainActivity$PlaceHolderFragment">

    <ListView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/listviewsorular" />


</FrameLayout>
```

And lastly here is my MainActivity.java file

```
package com.example.recreated.wedowhatwelearn;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

    }



    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment(){
        }
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

            return rootView;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Also import `Fragment` from `support library` like replace `android.app.Fragment;` with `android.support.v7.app.Fragment`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `PlaceholderFragment` is an `android.app.Fragment`. Since you are using the support `FragmentManager` (via `getSupportFragmentManager()`,), it needs to be an [`android.support.v4.app.Fragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html).

Simply change your import and everything should work fine.